# identifying and automating overlays that are hidden inside tags in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

how do we identify and run the overlays in the web driver. the overlay does not sit inside an i frame but it is in the different tag but the common parent, it is hidden in the normal flow, when one of the link is selected, the overlay pops up.

when the overlay is visible, i am able to find the element using x-path but the same will not work when i put the code in web driver, i am assuming we cannot use getWindowHandles(),

can anyone please advise?

thanks,

V

Comment: Can you show us what you mean? Post the html code, and/or screenshots of an overlay?

Comment: in the website https://www.t-mobile.co.uk/shop/pay-monthly/mobile-phones/    while adding a pay monthly phone, an overlay appears but the not able to select the button in the overlay

Comment: That kind of overlay isn't a real window, it's just a bunch of html dynamically created and styled. The buttons aren't `<input>` fields, but firebug can clearly see an `<a>` tag with this xpath: `.//a/span[text()='Buy it with 4G on EE']/..`